# Show and Hide multiple div after few seconds angular 2 / typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular2-template

Basically I am creating multiple divs by passing some data. And trying to hide the same divs based on some conditions.

It is creating multiple divs but it hides all divs irrespective of any condition.

If I pass "on: true" for one div, it hides all the div. It might be because of forEach loop which I am running on all elements. But not sure how to fix it.

Here is my typescript code--->

```js
export class ShowDataComponent implements OnInit {
 @ViewChildren('notification') private el:  QueryList<ElementRef>;
        this.showData= arrayData;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.showData.length; i++){
    this.on = this.showData[i].on;
    this.duration = this.showData[i].duration;
    if(this.on){  
   this.el.forEach((element)=>{      
     const htmlElement = element.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
     setTimeout(() => htmlElement.setAttribute("style", "display:none;"), this.duration);
   });
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Here is my HTML code--->

```html
<div *ngFor="let n of showData">
  <div #notification class="show-top-bar" style="display: block;">
      {{n.message}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It hides all divs because you put that `forEach` after `if(this.on){` which means that it requires only one item from **showData** array to have property **on** set to true.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're not supposed to handle the DOM yourself, it's the framework's job. And if you don't use the framework, what's the point of having one at all ?

Now I don't understand your code, because you don't have declared a `on` class member, and your code is made to hide all divs.

So I will assume you have a condition on your elements, called `on`, because it seems to be the closest from what you could expect.

Start with your HTML :

```
<div *ngFor="let n of showData">
  <div *ngIf="n.on" class="show-top-bar" style="display: block;">
      {{n.message}}
  </div>
</div>
```

You start by putting the condition on the `on` property of your element. Next, you set all the values to true to show them all, and create an array of values to use later :

```
constructor() {
  this.referenceArray = this.showData.map(n => ({id: n.id, on: n.on}));
  for (let n of this.showData) {
    n.on = true;
  }
}
```

Finally, you set all the properties to their initial value after a timeout :

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    for (let n of this.showData) {
      n.on = this.referenceArray.find(rn => rn.id === n.id).on;
    }
  });
}
```